# API Composition (BFF) using Spring and Reactor

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Imagine I have two microservices and I want to implement the BFF (Backend for the Frontend) pattern within a Spring REST controller which uses WebFlux.

The domain objects from the 2 remote services are:

```
public class Comment {
    private Long id;
    private String text;
    private Long authorId;
    private Long editorId;
}

public class Person {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

and the API Composer must return objects of following type:

```
public class ComposedComment {
    private String text;
    private String authorFullName;
    private String editorFullName;
}
```

For the sake of semplicity I wrote a Controller which simulates all the services in one.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Controller {

    private static final List<Comment> ALL_COMMENTS = Arrays.asList(//
            new Comment(1L, "Bla bla", 1L, null), //
            new Comment(2L, "lorem ipsum", 2L, 3L), //
            new Comment(3L, "a comment", 2L, 1L));
    private static final Map<Long, Person> PERSONS;

    static {
        PERSONS = new HashMap<>();
        PERSONS.put(1L, new Person(1L, "John", "Smith"));
        PERSONS.put(2L, new Person(2L, "Paul", "Black"));
        PERSONS.put(3L, new Person(3L, "Maggie", "Green"));
    }

    private WebClient clientCommentService = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/api");
    private WebClient clientPersonService = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/api");

    @GetMapping("/composed/comments")
    public Flux<ComposedComment> getComposedComments() {
     //This is the tricky part
    }

    private String extractFullName(Map<Long, Person> map, Long personId) {
        Person person = map.get(personId);
        return person == null ? null : person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName();
    }

    @GetMapping("/comments")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Comment>> getAllComments() {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Comment>>(ALL_COMMENTS, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/persons/{personIds}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Person>> getPersonsByIdIn(@PathVariable("personIds") Set<Long> personIds) {
        List<Person> persons = personIds.stream().map(id -> PERSONS.get(id)).filter(person -> person != null)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Person>>(persons, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

My problem is I have just began with Reactor and I am not really sure of what I am doing.. This is the current version of my composer method:

```
@GetMapping("/composed/comments")
public Flux<ComposedComment> getComposedComments() {
    Flux<Comment> commentFlux = clientCommentService.get().uri("/comments").retrieve().bodyToFlux(Comment.class);
    Set<Long> personIds = commentFlux.toStream().map(comment -> Arrays.asList(comment.getAuthorId(), comment.getEditorId())).flatMap(Collection::stream).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Map<Long, Person> personsById = clientPersonService.get().uri("/persons/{ids}", personIds.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","))).retrieve().bodyToFlux(Person.class).collectMap(Person::getId).block();
    return commentFlux.map(
            comment -> new ComposedComment(
                    comment.getText(),
                    extractFullName(personsById, comment.getAuthorId()),
                    extractFullName(personsById, comment.getEditorId()))
    );
}
```

It works, nevertheless I know I should make several transformations with map, flatMap and zip instead of invoking block() and toStream()... Can you please help me to rewrite this method correctly? :)

Comment: Avoid using `toStream` or other blocking operator. In your Spring 5 webflux environment you are never forced to block.

Comment: Hi @DanielJipa, thanks for your answer. The problem is, I cannot create an URI without first blocking on the mono/flux to get the String I will use as a uriVariables, as the WebClient.UriSpec doesn't have any reactive uri method: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.UriSpec.html
Or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Your domain model seems strange and also concatenate the personids to send it to the request path. As I understand there are multiple personids on the comment.

Comment: If thats the case on each comment on the flatMap concatenate the ids and send it to the personService.

Comment: yes it's right: each comment has 2 personIds: one for the author (which is never null) and one for the editor (which may be null if the comment didn't get edited). The idea is to collect all the comments from the commentService and then in 1 single further call collect all the persons which authored/modified any comments...

Comment: I will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

You should try the `zip` operator to compose the two publishers. And don't subscribe to the flux if you want to return it.

If you can't use the `zip` because the second publisher depends on results from the first then use `flatMap`.

You can use the flatMap like this:

```
commentsFlux.flatMap(comment -> personService.getPersonsByIds(comment.getPersonId1() + "," + comment.getPersonId2())
                                      //at this moment you have scope on both
                                      .map(listOfTwoPersons -> new Composed(listOfTwoPersons, comment))
```

N.B. I didn't worked with webflux client and I am just guessing from your working example it knows to wrap to a Flux/Mono even if you return an entity or list of entities.

Comment: If I do this:

Flux<Tuple2<Comment, List<Long>>> commentsWithPersonIds = Flux.zip(commentFlux,
                commentFlux.map(comment -> Arrays.asList(
                        comment.getEditorId() == null ? comment.getAuthorId() : comment.getEditorId(), comment.getAuthorId()))//editorId can be null, authorId not 
        ); 

I get Tuples with comments + ids of authors/editors. I should then make T2 flat, invoke the personService and somehow construct the ComposedComments?

Comment: put into other words: after i get commentsWithPersonIds tuples <comment1;{1,1}>,<comment2;{2,3}>,<comment3;{2,1}> I think i should merge all the tuples into one <{comment1, comment2, comment3};{1,2,3}>, then get the persons throug a map of T2s (here I invoke the person service through webclient) <{comment1,comment2,comment3};{person1,person2,person3}> and finally map this tuple into a Flux<ComposedComments>.. Is it right? If yes, how can I make commentsWithPersonIds flat? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are returning null in your controller.
Replace it by returning the reactive stream instead.

```
return commentFlux.flatMap(comment -> ....)
....
```

Your controller signature return a

```
Flux<ComposedComment>
```

so make sure in the last return, you have to use flatMap or map to transform them to ComposedComment. You could think it as a promise chain, where you can do many flatMap, map in the implementation to transform to a final dataset.

Don't use subscribe in these situations, subscribe is suitable for demonstrating the invoking process of the reactive stream or in somewhere in the app where the result calling the method not needed directly as this controller

At this time you just return a reactive stream by using map, flatMap, collect, zip...... Just return the reactive stream (Mono, Flux<>) then spring-webflux will invoke them.

Comment: return null is just to let it compile. I understand the problem with subscribing, nevertheless I am confused by the map chain to get the composed objects with a single call to the personService.. :(

Comment: Let me give you a rough example:

`map(classA -> classB)`

`flatMap(classA -> Mono<ClassA>)`


map apply a function to transform the original item into another trivial item,
flatMap can do more complex, it transform the original item into another stream (observable, Mono, or any reactive related stuff).

You can assign your implementation into a Flux<ComposeComment> variable.

Implement it gradually by inserting map, flatMap to see how they work, how the IDE notify errors then you will get it done!